# Accomplish to fix a large image inside of a scrollbar on the screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a ScrollViewer with an Image Control in it. It displays a rather large image. I want my user to be able to zoom into the image using gestures. I therefore enabled the ZoomMode on the Scrollviewer.

I like how display the image when it's disabled the Scrollviewer, because the image fits on the screen.

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <Image x:Name="sketchImageView" Stretch="Uniform"
                    />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

However the Scrollviewer automatically scrolls back to the left "edge" of the image whenever the user releases its finger, making effectively zooming in and out of the image impossible.

I also tried changing the visibility to auto, but when I do this, the image is expanded and I'd like to have it fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the scrollbars visibility to Auto and image to UnifomToFill

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image x:Name="sketchImageView" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                />
    </ScrollViewer>
```